# 22.04 LTS, kernel and new hardware: how to deal with all these?

Tags: drivers, kernel, lts

I have switch from EndeavourOS to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS for some reason related with my work. The thing is I have got few problems I haven't got on EndeavourOS (the last one was just ideal). So, the problems are:

- a notebook just doesn't turn off - after "waiting" rotation icon disappearing nothing happens - I'm forced to use power button for 4 second
- WiFi is very unstable: without any reason (that at home, 2m from router) it reconnects from time to time
- Bluetooth is very distance-dependent: literally on distance above 50-60 cm from notebook it starts to distort a sound

I guess the reason is used kernel is relatively old. I use Lenovo IdeaPad 5 Pro 16ACH6, and it isn't old notebook. But not sure what is official way to get more recent drivers for WiFi, Bluetooth, ACPI (or what)...

So, are there some degree of freedom concerning kernel/drivers upgrade on LTS?

```
▶ sudo inxi -Fxxrzc0
System:
  Kernel: 6.2.0-34-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A
    Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.24.7 tk: Qt 5.15.3 wm: kwin_x11 dm: SDDM
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 82L5 v: IdeaPad 5 Pro 16ACH6
    serial: <filter> Chassis: type: 10 v: IdeaPad 5 Pro 16ACH6 serial: <filter>
  Mobo: LENOVO model: LNVNB161216 v: No DPK serial: <filter> UEFI: LENOVO
    v: GSCN31WW date: 01/28/2022
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 45.3 Wh (59.2%) condition: 76.5/75.0 Wh (102.0%)
    volts: 15.8 min: 15.4 model: LGC L20L4PE1 serial: <filter> status: Charging
CPU:
  Info: 8-core model: AMD Ryzen 9 5900HX with Radeon Graphics bits: 64
    type: MT MCP arch: Zen 3 rev: 0 cache: L1: 512 KiB L2: 4 MiB L3: 16 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1206 high: 1300 min/max: 1200/4679 boost: enabled
    cores: 1: 1200 2: 1200 3: 1200 4: 1200 5: 1300 6: 1200 7: 1200 8: 1200
    9: 1200 10: 1200 11: 1200 12: 1200 13: 1200 14: 1200 15: 1200 16: 1200
    bogomips: 105395
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile] vendor: Lenovo
    driver: nouveau v: kernel pcie: speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 8 bus-ID: 01:00.0
    chip-ID: 10de:25a2
  Device-2: AMD Cezanne vendor: Lenovo driver: amdgpu v: kernel pcie:
    speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 16 ports: active: eDP-1 empty: DP-1,HDMI-A-1
    bus-ID: 05:00.0 chip-ID: 1002:1638
  Device-3: Chicony Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
    bus-ID: 3-4:3 chip-ID: 04f2:b6be
  Display: server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 compositor: kwin_x11 driver: X:
    loaded: amdgpu,ati unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa gpu: amdgpu
    display-ID: :0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 2560x1600 s-dpi: 96
  Monitor-1: eDP res: 2560x1600 dpi: 188 diag: 407mm (16")
  OpenGL: renderer: RENOIR (renoir LLVM 15.0.7 DRM 3.49 6.2.0-34-generic)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio vendor: Lenovo
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie: speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 16
    bus-ID: 05:00.1 chip-ID: 1002:1637
  Device-2: AMD Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
    vendor: Lenovo driver: N/A pcie: speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 16 bus-ID: 05:00.5
    chip-ID: 1022:15e2
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h HD Audio vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel pcie: speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 16 bus-ID: 05:00.6 chip-ID: 1022:15e3
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.2.0-34-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: no
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8852AE 802.11ax PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    vendor: Lenovo driver: rtw89_8852ae v: kernel pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s
    lanes: 1 port: 2000 bus-ID: 03:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8852
  IF: wlo1 state: down mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter type: USB
    driver: r8152 bus-ID: 2-2:2 chip-ID: 0bda:8153
  IF: enx00e04c681b60 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-1: docker0 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-2: gpd0 state: down mac: N/A
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Realtek Bluetooth Radio type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
    bus-ID: 3-3:2 chip-ID: 0bda:4852
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 2 state: up address: <filter>
    bt-v: 3.0 lmp-v: 5.2 sub-v: 6d7a
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 953.87 GiB lvm-free: 20.36 GiB
    used: 156.71 GiB (16.4%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Western Digital
    model: PC SN730 SDBPNTY-1T00-1101 size: 953.87 GiB speed: 31.6 Gb/s
    lanes: 4 serial: <filter> temp: 22.9 C
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 913.75 GiB used: 156.42 GiB (17.1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-1
    mapped: vgubuntu-root
  ID-2: /boot size: 1.61 GiB used: 290.5 MiB (17.7%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-3: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 6.1 MiB (1.2%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 1.91 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2
    dev: /dev/dm-2 mapped: vgubuntu-swap_1
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 50.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Repos:
  Packages: 3316 note: see --pkg apt: 3297 snap: 19
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list
    1: deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
    2: deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
    3: deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
    4: deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
    5: deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
    6: deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
    7: deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    8: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
    9: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
    10: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/aslatter-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list
    1: deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/aslatter/ppa/ubuntu/ jammy main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubuntu-ppa-ubuntu-backports-jammy.list
    1: deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu/ jammy main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64,armhf,arm64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/22.04/prod jammy main
Info:
  Processes: 485 Uptime: 2m Memory: 27.25 GiB used: 2.91 GiB (10.7%)
  Init: systemd v: 249 runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 11.4.0 alt: 11 Shell: Sudo
  v: 1.9.9 running-in: konsole inxi: 3.3.13
```

Comment: Attach more system info: `inxi -Fxxrzc0` in terminal. `sudo apt install inxi` if command not found

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Hmmm. Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server? Exactly what kernel are you using? What others are available at GRUB? A proper install of Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 should be using kernel 6.2 (HWE), which is not "relatively old."

Comment: Yes, Desktop is in use with 6.2.0-34 kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 6.5 OEM kernel:

```
sudo apt install linux-oem-22.04d
```

Reboot.